# Custom Installer: What files do I need?

Tags: c#, deployment, installation

I'm using VS 2010 Express and I've written an app that I want to deploy.  I've decided to use a custom installer and I need to know, other than my `.exe` and `.dll` files, which files from the `release\bin` folder do I need to copy to the installer?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If its a library/windows executable, that is all you need. If its web app, you need other files (aspx, config, js, css etc.)

Comment: That should be included as a resource in the `exe` or `dll`.

Comment: So it's automatically included in the `.exe` at compile time?

Comment: Yeah. Make sure its Build action is set to `Embedded Resource`

Comment: Is that just on the main `.cs` file?